# How do I style specific words when it gets fetched from my MySQLI database in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have data being fetched from MySQLI database. I want to style "Small" so it looks like this: [image]

Here is what my table looks like in PHP. I am unsure how to style specific words from fetched data.

[image]

Here's my PHP code:

```
    <?php

    $connect = mysqli_connect( 'placeholder','placeholder','placeholder','placeholder');
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM databasename";
    $result = $connect->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while ($row = $result-> fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "<tr><td>" . $row["item_name"] . "</td>
                      <td>" . $row["item_cooldown"] . "</td>
                      <td>" . $row["item_effect"] . "</td>
                      <td>" . $row["item_passive"] . "</td>
                      <td>" . $row["item_cost"] . "</td>
                      <td>" . $row["item_type"] . "</td> 
                      <td>" . $row["item_size"] . "</td></tr>";
        }
    } 
    else {
        echo "No Results";
    }
    $connect->close();
    ?>

</table>
```

Any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Add a span inside the related cell (the last td tag pair) and make a css class to style it.

You could even have different colours for different data if you make a base class and a modifier class that is either applied using if/else or switch, or just use the data as the class name if they're single-word.

---

Completely untested, but shouldn't be too far off. I used single quotes to not conflict with the double quotes of the html syntax. My PHP might be a bit rusty.

```
'<td>
  <span class="sizetag'  . $row['item_size'] . '">' . $row['item_size'] . '</span>
</td>'
```

CSS

```
.sizetag {
  border-radius 3px
  padding: .5em
}

.large {
  background-color: green
}
```

Then supply with the classes you need and adjust the colours until they are nice and the text is stil readable.

If you don't want to use the data name as a class you could do the following which uses colour name (or whatever you need) instead.

I would place this inside the while:

```
$color = ""

switch ($row['item_size']) {
  small:
    $color = 'bg-green';
    break;
  medium:
    $color = 'bg-red';
    break;
  large:
    $color = 'bg-yellow';
    break;
}
```

And this to replace the last td

```
'<td>
  <span class="sizetag'  . $color . '">' . $row['item_size'] . '</span>
</td>'
```

And again supply with the classes you need and adjust the colours until they are nice and the text is stil readable.

Comment: Thanks. I think that the second option you gave is the way I'll go as I also want the word "Medium" to be yellow and "Large" to be red. I am unsure how to do this though. Is there any way you could expand on it a bit or direct me somewhere that could explain how to do it? Appreciate the help.

Comment: @Swampz I added some example code

Answer (score 0):

to your last <td> tag change it to:

```
<td style='backgroundColor:green'> ...
```